# document.getElementByName()[0] undefined

Tags: javascript

This is my js function

```
function toggleCountry(country)
{
    var elem = document.getElementsByName(country)[0].value;
    alert(elem);
}
```

Its being called onclick event

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleCountry('usa');"><div class="navBarItems">USA</div></a>
```

I have another div with the attribute name="usa" and I want to search for it and disable the text. However, I always get undefined as it returns in my alert.

Edit: Its a div tag.

Comment: What kind of element is `name="usa"`?

Comment: sorry, its a div actually.

Comment: We need more context/info.  My test case worked fine which means something else (that you did not include here) is causing the issue.  Post markup please

Comment: @user3469990: `<div>` elements don't have a `.value`.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. Do I have to iterate through the nodeList to get the name?

Comment: @Jonny: What name?  What are you trying to do?  You probably just want `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`.

Comment: if just one div is to have name='usa' use id='usa' and document.getElementById  instead and .innerHTML

Comment: @RocketHazmat <div class="content" name="usa"> is my html. There is no content in there, its only a container.

Comment: @jing3142 My div will have the same name, as ID is a unique identifier. I will have multiple div tags with the name=usa

Comment: @Jonny: What *value* are you trying to get?  If there's no content, then what are you trying to alert?

Comment: @RocketHazmat From my understanding, getElementByName returns a ListNode/array. I will have multiple divs with the name = "usa" attribute. I would like to look for a div with the name = "usa" and edit its css assocaited with it. Is that possible?

Comment: Why are you using a name and not a class or data attribute?

Comment: Sounds like the problem you are trying to solve is different from the one written. Perhaps you should think the problem through and re-write. Could be you should be using class not name.

Comment: @Jonny: Edit CSS?  If that's the problem here, then why are you `alert`ing stuff and using `.value`?

Comment: @jing3142 Yeah, I'm begging to think I should use class and not name. I have class now, but I will re-write the problem and hopefully the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah, I made a mistake with that one. I think I should be using class instead

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByName(name)` requires that you make use of the `name=""` attribute.

With that in place, try changing:

`var elem = document.getElementsByName(country)[0].value;`

To:

`var elem = document.getElementsByName(country)[0].innerHTML;`

(provided this is your goal)

`.value` is the wrong method here (there's no value attribute on your element). I was able to access the `.innerHTML` just fine, so your function is selecting the appropriate element. If `.innerHTML` is not what you want, you can substitute that for another method. I'm not entirely sure what you're reaching for here, but hopefully this jsfiddle helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/S68qr/

Comment: He clearly states in the question that he has an element with attribute `name="usa"` on his page, and `country` is already a string passed to the function so it doesn't need quotes around it in the call to `getElementsByName()`.  This is not an answer it's a comment.

Comment: Oh, he just said he's using a `name` attribute on a `div`... that's the problem.  Your `innerHTML` solution should work for him, or even just `getElementByID` and using IDs instead of the `name` attribute.  Changed my downvote to an upvote :)

Comment: From my understanding, getElementByName returns a ListNode/array. I will have multiple divs with the name = "usa" attribute. I would like to look for a div with the name = "usa" and edit its css assocaited with it. Is that possible?

Comment: @epascarello Sure it is... there's no `value=""` attribute present on these elements.

Comment: Div's do not have a name attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Comment: @epascarello: They *can*.

Comment: @Jonny In that case you need to implement a for loop around the body of your function that applies your updates to each instance of 'usa'. Coding that up feels a tad beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your implementation and Stuart Kershaw already provided a great solution.

Another approach would be to change your HTML to provide a more dynamic selection.

```
    <select onchange="toggleCountry(this.value)">
       <option value="USA">USA</option>
       <option value="CDN">CDN</option>
    </select>
```

And you can use this function to retrieve the value.

```
function toggleCountry(country)
{
    alert(country);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LzubU/